# perl regex - extract words between 2 separators

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have a text file which looks like:

```
entrez*gene/locuslink:"BRCA2(IV)"|entrez*gene/locuslink:At4g00020@entrez*gene/locuslink:RAD51|entrez*gene /locuslink:At5g20850@
entrez*gene/locuslink:"BRCA2(IV)"|entrez*gene/locuslink:At4g00020@entrez*gene/locuslink:DMC1|entrez*gene/locuslink:At3g22880@
```

I wish to extract the words between : and @ separators using perl in unix
the output should be:

```
At4g00020  At5g20850
At4g00020  At3g22880
```

I did:

```
perl -l -ne '/:["At"]([^@]*)/ and print($1,"\t",$2)
```

with no success
thanks in advance for your help

Tom.

Comment: If your's string format always remain as shown above than you can first split your string on `:` using `perl -F/:/` and than try to use regex on the smaller string parts which are stored in `@F` array. I believe this way your regex will be less complicated. For more info on `F` argument look at `perldoc perlrun`. I came up with [this](http://sprunge.us/EHYH) although not the best possible solution but an alternative

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problem with your regexp.

First of all, [...] denotes a character class matching one of the chars inside the brackets. This means that `["At"]` wil match one of the characters '"', 'A', or 't'. Leave out the brackets and double-quotes..

Second, you want to collect multiple matches. This can be done by using the /g modifier in list context:

```
perl -lne '@result = /:At([^@]*)/g; print join("\t", @result)'
```

Finaly, based on the expected output, you need to capture At as well:

```
perl -lne '@result = /:(At[^@]*)/g; print join("\t", @result)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
perl -l -ne '/:(?=At)([^@]*)/ and print($1,"\t",$2)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
perl -l -ne '/:([^:@]*)@.*:([^:@]*)@/ and print($1,"\t",$2)'
```

Searches for `:`, a string without the separators follows, `@` closes it.